# Different Angular Material Typographies for different screen sizes

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, typography

**Current situation:** I have defined an angular material typography for my project like below:

```
$typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: Text,

  $headline: mat.define-typography-level(
    $font-size: 53px,
    $font-weight: bold,
  )
);

$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  typography: $typography,
));

@include mat.core($theme);
@include mat.core-theme($theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

**Need:** Now I need to define one more typograph for small screen.

**Attempts:** I have used multiple `mat.define-typography-config` in multiple media queries but I received error: "The same typography styles are generated multiple times."